# How to Subtract row by row in Power Bi?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

[image]

In this dataset I am trying to develop a column or a measure based upon the hours column. I am trying to determine the difference between the first and second hour rows, the second and third hour rows, etc. and all the way through the entirety of the data.

Note: there are multiple serial numbers in this table; I just used this serial as an example.

Comment: You should use LAG (with partitioning). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 When posting questions it is much better to provide sample data as text instead of images. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this should be tagged with `SQL-Server` unless you can change the SQL that sources the data. If so you could pre-calculate this inside SQL Server.

If you can change the Power Query that brings the data into the data model you can add an Index column as the data's coming in and use that.

Please see:
[How to Compare the Current Row to the Previous Row Using DAX](https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/03/how-to-compare-the-current-row-to-the-previous-row-in-power-pivot/)